# purpose of adding events layer in DDD

Tags: spring, tdd, domain-driven-design, event-sourcing

I was going through with https://github.com/spring-guides/deprecate-tut-web  tutorial on Spring. I am new to Spring . I have seen a few small Spring Web MVC tutorials before . Most other tutorials i have seen uses a service layer which is invoked from the web controller. But never have i seen the use of "events" layer as used in this tutorial. Is the layer really necessary, and if so what benefit does it give me ?  I am also new to both DDD (Domain Driven Development) and TDD (Test Driven Development), some things just seem really redundant and over-complicated to me in this tutorial .. Can someone explain what is the purpose of this events layer and why should we use it ? Thank you in advance and sorry if it's a Noob question. :)

Comment: Is your question about events or the layer ? A whole layer dedicated to events may be overkill. They are basically part of the Domain, so you can perfectly put them in the Domain layer.

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of domain events are notify any interested party that something has occurred in one of your domain objects. For example, if you hear a business expert say something such as "**when** an invoice is approved, release payment", then you probably want a domain event called InvoiceApproved.  This way the payment related code can subscribe to that in the application layer and not be tightly coupled to the invoice logic and orchestration.  Domain events are a very necessary and very powerful aspect of DDD.